# How to get imge base of current setting through script in IDA pro？

Tags: ida, idapython

As a beginner I'm trying to disassemble a file with IDA Pro 6.5. 
I know that the image base can be find in IDA Pro manu Edit -> Segment -> Rebase program.

Now, I want to get the image base of current setting through IDC or IDAPython. Are there anyone to tell me how to write script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`idaapi.get_imagebase()` is your friend.

Just in case you didn't know, all the reference documentation for idapython is [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)

Example:

```
Python>hex(idaapi.get_imagebase())
0x100000L
```

Comment: My firend, You mean that I should wirte a plug-in for get image base? but I just want to get image base through IDC or IDAPython?

Comment: No. Just run this function from the python command line near "Python" button or from "File-->Script command" dialog.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you so much! My friend.

Answer (score 3):

idc unattended

```
F:\IDA_FRE_5>del outtext.txt & idag.exe -A -S.\segbase.idc c:\WINDOWS\system32\c
alc.idb & sleep 5 & type outtext.txt
Segment Base is 1001000

F:\IDA_FRE_5>type segbase.idc
#include <idc.idc>
static main ()
{
auto fpo,fullstr,segbase;
        Batch(1);
        segbase = SegStart(MinEA());
        Message("base is %x\n",segbase);
        fpo = fopen("outtext.txt","wb");
        fullstr = form("Segment Base is %x\n",segbase);
        writestr(fpo,fullstr);
        fclose(fpo);
        Exit(0);

}

F:\IDA_FRE_5>
```

Comment: Unattended... Nice touch! :)